# Program crashes on UpdateWindow when dynamically creating CStatic with SS_OWNERDRAW

Tags: c++, mfc

On init dialog I dynamically create some `CStatic` controls with `SS_OWNERDRAW` style. The program crashes, when I make these controls visible (`WS_VISIBLE` or `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`). Call stack shows what crashes on a method `DrawItem`.

I don't know why because I have picture control added in resource manager and there are no error with it. The thing is, I need to create a certain quantity of controls depending on the frames count.

Code snippet:

```
CStatic* frameWnd = new CStatic;
if(frameWnd->Create(_T("my static"), WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD | SS_OWNERDRAW, frameRect, this) != 1)
    MessageBox("Failed!");
m_oaFrames.Add(frameWnd);
```

So, question is: I should override `DrawItem` method for `frameWnd` or is there another solution?

Comment: Thanks to anonymous for useless negative evaluation.

Comment: It's not crashing. The debugger is reminding you that you must override `CStatic::DrawItem` as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem you should create custom control and override `DrawItem` method like this:

```
class CPictureCtrl : public CStatic
{
public:
    CPictureCtrl() {}
    ~CPictureCtrl() {}
protected:
    virtual void PreSubclassWindow()
    {
        CStatic::PreSubclassWindow();
        ModifyStyle(0, SS_OWNERDRAW);
    }
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct){}
private:
};
```